# Part of window is inaccessible

Tags: openshot

As you can see, I am unable to access the "Export Video" button at the bottom of the window. I managed by using Tab to cycle over all the fields. I would like to know if there is another way around, a better way to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great work-around, but if you press alt-space, the submenu allowing resize and moving windows appears.  You could then resize the window vertically, to be able to access the whole window and get to the buttons.